# forgot passwords for postgresql users. how do I login?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-11.04

I forgot passwords for postgresql root user: postgres

So I changed `pg_hba.conf` to have `trust` method for everything (this is my local dev box)

```
local   all         postgres                          trust
local   all         all                               trust
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

after restarting the service it is still asking me for password.

```
@omnipresent:~$ su - postgres
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Though, I can login as by `psql -U postgres`

```
@omnipresent:~$ psql -U postgres
psql (8.4.8)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

the mess I am in, at this point I'd just like to make a new role for postgresql and make that user an admin.

How can I do that being in this situation?

Comment: The key here is that system accounts (what you are logging into with `su`) and postgresql accounts (what you are logging into with `psql`) are entirely different sets of accounts.  Use Antonius's advice to change the system password for the "postgres" system user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the password of any linux user, including the Postgres root:

```
sudo passwd postgres
```

Then:

```
su - postgres
psql -U postgres template1 -c alter user postgres with password 'newpassword';
```

Comment: Don't forget to tighten up your pg_hba.conf when you are done too.

Comment: the psql needed quotes for me:
`psql -U postgres template1 -c "alter user postgres with password 'newpassword'"`